# I am getting a strange error when running MPICH 4.0.3

Tags: linux, bash, netcdf, mpich, ubuntu-22.04

I am getting an error when running mpirun:

```
will@will-MS-7D91:~/WRFHYDRO/Tests/Compatibility$ mpirun ./a.out |& tee comp_test2.txt
   C function called by Fortran
   Values are xx =  2.00 and ii = 1 
Abort(2139535) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(176)........: 
MPID_Init(1538)..............: 
MPIDI_OFI_mpi_init_hook(1511): 
open_fabric(2565)............: 
find_provider(2683)..........: OFI fi_getinfo() failed (ofi_init.c:2683:find_provider:No data available)
```

I have tested the commands on another computer and it works fine.  The commands are this:

```
echo "Test 2"
mpifort -c 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_f.f
mpicc -c 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_c.c
mpifort 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_f.o \
02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_c.o \
     -L${NETCDF}/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf

mpirun ./a.out |& tee comp_test2.txt
```

I recently built a new pc, with an MSI Z790 Tomahawk board, Intel-13900K cpu, and 64GB of DDR5 5600mhz RAM.  Could this be this issue were one of those things are not compatibile with mpich?  Mpich version is 4.0.3.

```
sudo apt -y update
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y install gcc gfortran g++ libtool automake autoconf make m4 default-jre default-jdk csh ksh git python3 python3-dev python2 python2-dev mlocate curl cmake libcurl4-openssl-dev

echo " "
##############################Directory Listing############################
export HOME=`cd;pwd`

mkdir $HOME/WRF
export WRF_FOLDER=$HOME/WRF
cd $WRF_FOLDER/
mkdir Downloads
mkdir WRFPLUS
mkdir WRFDA
mkdir Libs
export DIR=$WRF_FOLDER/Libs
mkdir Libs/grib2
mkdir Libs/NETCDF
mkdir Libs/MPICH
mkdir -p Tests/Environment
mkdir -p Tests/Compatibility

echo " "
#############################Core Management####################################

export CPU_CORE=$(nproc)                                             # number of available threads on system
export CPU_6CORE="6"
export CPU_HALF=$(($CPU_CORE / 2))                                   #half of availble cores on system
export CPU_HALF_EVEN=$(( $CPU_HALF - ($CPU_HALF % 2) ))              #Forces CPU cores to even number to avoid partial core export. ie 7 cores would be 3.5 cores.

if [ $CPU_CORE -le $CPU_6CORE ]                                  #If statement for low core systems.  Forces computers to only use 1 core if there are 4 cores or less on the system.
then
  export CPU_HALF_EVEN="2"
else
  export CPU_HALF_EVEN=$(( $CPU_HALF - ($CPU_HALF % 2) ))
fi


echo "##########################################"
echo "Number of Threads being used $CPU_HALF_EVEN"
echo "##########################################"


echo " "
##############################Downloading Libraries############################
#Force use of ipv4 with -4
cd Downloads
wget -c -4 https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.13.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5/archive/refs/tags/hdf5-1_13_2.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/archive/refs/tags/v4.9.0.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran/archive/refs/tags/v4.6.0.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/releases/download/v4.0.3/mpich-4.0.3.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.39.tar.gz
wget -c -4 https://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/software/jasper-1.900.1.zip
wget -c -4 https://sourceforge.net/projects/opengrads/files/grads2/2.2.1.oga.1/Linux%20%2864%20Bits%29/opengrads-2.2.1.oga.1-bundle-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-glibc_2.17.tar.gz



echo " "
####################################Compilers#####################################
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
export FC=gfortran
export F77=gfortran
export CFLAGS="-fPIC -fPIE -O3"



#IF statement for GNU compiler issue
export GCC_VERSION=$(/usr/bin/gcc -dumpfullversion | awk '{print$1}')
export GFORTRAN_VERSION=$(/usr/bin/gfortran -dumpfullversion | awk '{print$1}')
export GPLUSPLUS_VERSION=$(/usr/bin/g++ -dumpfullversion | awk '{print$1}')

export GCC_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $GCC_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}')
export GFORTRAN_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $GFORTRAN_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}')
export GPLUSPLUS_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $GPLUSPLUS_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}')

export version_10="10"

if [ $GCC_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION -ge $version_10 ] || [ $GFORTRAN_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION -ge $version_10 ] || [ $GPLUSPLUS_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION -ge $version_10 ]
then
  export fallow_argument=-fallow-argument-mismatch
  export boz_argument=-fallow-invalid-boz
else
  export fallow_argument=
  export boz_argument=
fi


export FFLAGS=$fallow_argument
export FCFLAGS=$fallow_argument


echo "##########################################"
echo "FFLAGS = $FFLAGS"
echo "FCFLAGS = $FCFLAGS"
echo "##########################################"




echo " "
#############################zlib############################
#Uncalling compilers due to comfigure issue with zlib1.2.13
#With CC & CXX definied ./configure uses different compiler Flags

cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
tar -xvzf v1.2.13.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.13/
./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check

echo " "
##############################MPICH############################
#F90= due to compiler issues with mpich install
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
tar -xvzf mpich-4.0.3.tar.gz
cd mpich-4.0.3/
F90= ./configure --prefix=$DIR/MPICH --with-device=ch3 FFLAGS=$fallow_argument FCFLAGS=$fallow_argument

make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
# make check



export PATH=$DIR/MPICH/bin:$PATH

export MPIFC=$DIR/MPICH/bin/mpifort
export MPIF77=$DIR/MPICH/bin/mpifort
export MPIF90=$DIR/MPICH/bin/mpifort
export MPICC=$DIR/MPICH/bin/mpicc
export MPICXX=$DIR/MPICH/bin/mpicxx


echo " "
#############################libpng############################
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
export LDFLAGS=-L$DIR/grib2/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I$DIR/grib2/include
tar -xvzf libpng-1.6.39.tar.gz
cd libpng-1.6.39/
CC=$MPICC FC=$MPIFC F77=$MPIF77 F90=$MPIF90 CXX=$MPICXX ./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check
echo " "
#############################JasPer############################
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
unzip jasper-1.900.1.zip
cd jasper-1.900.1/
./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2
CC=$MPICC FC=$MPIFC F77=$MPIF77 F90=$MPIF90 CXX=$MPICXX ./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check

export JASPERLIB=$DIR/grib2/lib
export JASPERINC=$DIR/grib2/include


echo " "
#############################hdf5 library for netcdf4 functionality############################
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
tar -xvzf hdf5-1_13_2.tar.gz
cd hdf5-hdf5-1_13_2
CC=$MPICC FC=$MPIFC F77=$MPIF77 F90=$MPIF90 CXX=$MPICXX ./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2 --with-zlib=$DIR/grib2 --enable-hl --enable-fortran
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check

export HDF5=$DIR/grib2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/grib2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


echo " "
##############################Install NETCDF C Library############################
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
tar -xzvf v4.9.0.tar.gz
cd netcdf-c-4.9.0/
export CPPFLAGS=-I$DIR/grib2/include
export LDFLAGS=-L$DIR/grib2/lib
export LIBS="-lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lcurl -lgfortran -lgcc -lm -ldl"
CC=$MPICC FC=$MPIFC CXX=$MPICXX F90=$MPIF90 F77=$MPIF77 ./configure --prefix=$DIR/NETCDF --disable-dap --enable-netcdf-4 --enable-netcdf4 --enable-shared
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check

export PATH=$DIR/NETCDF/bin:$PATH
export NETCDF=$DIR/NETCDF
echo " "
##############################NetCDF fortran library############################
cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
tar -xvzf v4.6.0.tar.gz
cd netcdf-fortran-4.6.0/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/NETCDF/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPPFLAGS="-I$DIR/NETCDF/include -I$DIR/grib2/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/NETCDF/lib -L$DIR/grib2/lib"
export LIBS="-lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -ldl"
CC=$MPICC FC=$MPIFC CXX=$MPICXX F90=$MPIF90 F77=$MPIF77 ./configure --prefix=$DIR/NETCDF --enable-netcdf-4 --enable-netcdf4 --enable-shared
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN
make -j $CPU_HALF_EVEN install |& tee make.install.log
#make check

echo " "
#################################### System Environment Tests ##############

cd $WRF_FOLDER/Downloads
wget -c -4 https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compile_tutorial/tar_files/Fortran_C_NETCDF_MPI_tests.tar
wget -c -4 https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compile_tutorial/tar_files/Fortran_C_tests.tar

tar -xvf Fortran_C_tests.tar -C $WRF_FOLDER/Tests/Environment
tar -xvf Fortran_C_NETCDF_MPI_tests.tar -C $WRF_FOLDER/Tests/Compatibility

export one="1"
echo " "
############## Testing Environment #####

cd $WRF_FOLDER/Tests/Environment

echo " "
echo " "
echo "Environment Testing "
echo "Test 1"
gfortran TEST_1_fortran_only_fixed.f
./a.out |& tee env_test1.txt
export TEST_PASS=$(grep -w -o -c "SUCCESS" env_test1.txt | awk  '{print$1}')
 if [ $TEST_PASS -ge 1 ]
    then
      echo "Enviroment Test 1 Passed"
    else
      echo "Environment Compiler Test 1 Failed"
      exit
  fi
read -t 3 -p "I am going to wait for 3 seconds only ..."

echo " "
echo "Test 2"
gfortran TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90
./a.out |& tee env_test2.txt
export TEST_PASS=$(grep -w -o -c "SUCCESS" env_test2.txt | awk  '{print$1}')
 if [ $TEST_PASS -ge 1 ]
    then
      echo "Enviroment Test 2 Passed"
    else
      echo "Environment Compiler Test 2 Failed"
      exit
  fi
echo " "
read -t 3 -p "I am going to wait for 3 seconds only ..."

echo " "
echo "Test 3"
gcc TEST_3_c_only.c
./a.out |& tee env_test3.txt
export TEST_PASS=$(grep -w -o -c "SUCCESS" env_test3.txt | awk  '{print$1}')
 if [ $TEST_PASS -ge 1 ]
    then
      echo "Enviroment Test 3 Passed"
    else
      echo "Environment Compiler Test 3 Failed"
      exit
  fi
echo " "
read -t 3 -p "I am going to wait for 3 seconds only ..."

echo " "
echo "Test 4"
gcc -c -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c
gfortran -c -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.f90
gfortran -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_f.o TEST_4_fortran+c_c.o
./a.out |& tee env_test4.txt
export TEST_PASS=$(grep -w -o -c "SUCCESS" env_test4.txt | awk  '{print$1}')
 if [ $TEST_PASS -ge 1 ]
    then
      echo "Enviroment Test 4 Passed"
    else
      echo "Environment Compiler Test 4 Failed"
      exit
  fi
echo " "
read -t 3 -p "I am going to wait for 3 seconds only ..."

echo " "
############## Testing Environment #####

cd $WRF_FOLDER/Tests/Compatibility

cp ${NETCDF}/include/netcdf.inc .

echo " "
echo " "
echo "Library Compatibility Tests "
echo "Test 1"
gfortran -c 01_fortran+c+netcdf_f.f
gcc -c 01_fortran+c+netcdf_c.c
gfortran 01_fortran+c+netcdf_f.o 01_fortran+c+netcdf_c.o \
     -L${NETCDF}/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf

     ./a.out |& tee comp_test1.txt
     export TEST_PASS=$(grep -w -o -c "SUCCESS" comp_test1.txt | awk  '{print$1}')
      if [ $TEST_PASS -ge 1 ]
         then
           echo "Compatibility Test 1 Passed"
         else
           echo "Compatibility Compiler Test 1 Failed"
           exit
       fi
     echo " "
     read -t 3 -p "I am going to wait for 3 seconds only ..."

echo " "

echo "Test 2"
mpifort -c 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_f.f
mpicc -c 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_c.c
mpifort 02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_f.o \
02_fortran+c+netcdf+mpi_c.o \
     -L${NETCDF}/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf

mpirun ./a.out |& tee comp_test2.txt
```

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: shared in the question at the bottom.  That's the commands and files I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue was having the intel mpi program in the $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Once I removed the intel mpi program from the both of those places in .bashrc it fixed the issue.